# Cast between pointer-to-member and pointer-to-const-member

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, constants, pointer-to-member

I've tried searching for this but every term I think of ends up with totally unrelated results.

I have a function (template) that takes a pointer-to-member as a parameter, but I cannot seem to implicitly treat the member being pointed to as const. Using const_cast works, but I'd like to avoid having to explicitly call it if I can.

```
struct MyStruct
{
  int *_array;
  int _size;
};

template<typename C, typename T>
void DoSomething(T* C::* arr, int siz)
{
  // do some read-only stuff with the member here
}

template<typename C, typename T>
void ConstDoSomething(T* C::* arr, int siz)
{
  DoSomething<C, T const>(arr, siz);
  // DoSomething<C, T const>(const_cast<T const* C::*>(arr), siz); // works
}

MyStruct ms;
ConstDoSomething<MyStruct const, int>(&MyStruct::_array, ms._size); // note:   cannot convert ‘arr’ (type ‘int* MyStruct::*’) to type ‘const int* MyStruct::*’
```

This is a simplified example that demonstrates the problem I'm having with a more complex class tree. I'm trying to avoid the cast because it would be required by the calling code (e.g., the person using the class template(s)).

---

**UPDATE:** When I first posted this I accidentally used a code sample that didn't generate the same error. It took me a fair amount of testing to determine the root cause, which was that I'm adding the const qualifier in the template arguments. The above sample now properly demonstrates the behavior I'm using.

Comment: For what it's worth, I compiled your code fragment successfully on llvm 5.0, mingw gcc 4.7.0 and 4.7.2.  Can you update your mingw installation or maybe include a complete program in the post?

Comment: I don't know what I was doing last night that I thought this snippet gave the same results. **Everything** I have tried to duplicate it short of using my full 550+ line program is compiling fine. I've clearly made some stupid mistake elsewhere. If I can't find it then I guess I'll post the full code here. :/

Comment: The code sample has been updated. Please advise if you have any additional details, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

What compiler do you use? I've tried your code Visual Studio 2012 and 2013 and it was compiled without any warnings or errors.
Either way - you should try const_cast instead of static_cast when you are playing with constness

Comment: I've actually read elsewhere that when it comes to adding const that static_cast and const_cast should work the same, and that const_cast is only needed for removing cv-qualifiers. Contrary to that, using const_cast lets it compile. Poking around my mingw folder seems to indicate that it's 4.7.1. I'm using Code::Blocks 12.11 as my IDE, with the mingw package that was bundled with it.

Comment: Additionally, I'll add, it was my mistake thinking that this snippet yielded the same results. I've clearly mucked something else up somewhere. I'll have to try and track that down. Thanks!

Comment: I updated the code sample, and it now accurately reflects the error (using gcc 4.7).

Answer (score 0):

In lieu of a better solution (for now at least), I'm creating a separate overload to accept a pointer-to-non-const-member and then use const_cast to call the originating methods.

As noted, the sample above was for simplicity and clarity's sake, but in actuality I am using several class templates, each inheriting from the other, and so forth. This has resulted in the following rather ugly solution:

```
// C = containing class (for pointer-to-members, std::nullptr_t if none)
// T = type of data being referenced

template<typename _C, typename _T> struct MakeMemberPointer // STL doesn't provide this??
{
public:
  typedef _T _C::* Type;
};

// Note: base-class template has specialization for C == std::nullptr_t
typedef typename std::conditional<std::is_same<C, decltype(nullptr)>::value,
  T const* C::*,
  T const*
>::type N;

typedef typename std::conditional<std::is_member_pointer<T>::value,
  typename MakeMemberPointer<
    C,
    typename std::add_pointer<
      typename std::remove_const<
        typename std::remove_reference<
          decltype(*(static_cast<C*>(nullptr)->*static_cast<N>(nullptr))) // T const&
        >::type // reference removed -> T const
      >::type // const removed -> T
    >::type // pointer added -> T*
  >::Type, // member pointer -> T* C::*
  typename std::add_pointer<typename std::remove_const<typename std::remove_pointer<N>::type>::type>::type
>::type NNoConst;

void DoSomething(N t) noexcept
{
}

void DoSomething(NNoConst t) noexcept
{
  DoSomething(const_cast<N>(t));
}
```

The class containing all of this is a const-only class derived from a non-const base class (but used here with const members due to template arguments). Declaring all this inside the class is highly preferable (to me) over having to use const_cast in the calling code, but I still don't see why gcc isn't allowing this conversion implicitly (after all, it's just **adding** const qualifiers!!).

Comment: Actually, upon further reflecting on what I'm doing... It's really a lot simpler to just abstract the const out higher up in the class template tree and provide a separate typedef for the non-const.